# Core Data is saving only last item

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a `function` with a `entity` and a `item`,and append the value in an `array`, but it adds only the last item and I think it's because every time I iterate through the array I append the value in the same `instance`.I can't figure out why.
My function:

```
func saveItem(itemToSave: String, key: String){
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Recipe", in: managedContext)
let item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: managedContext)
item.setValue(itemToSave, forKey: key)
do{
    try managedContext.save()
    recipes.append(item)
}catch{
    print("\(error)")
}}
```

How I call the function:

```
if let title = self.newRecipeView.titleTextField.text{
    saveItem(itemToSave: title, key: "title")
}
```

First image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrLbi.png
Second image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjiEP.png

The action when I click the button:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                clearView.alpha = 1
                self.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                activityIndicator.startAnimating()
                }, completion: { (true) in

                    if let title = self.newRecipeView.titleTextField.text{
                        saveItem(itemToSave: title, key: "title")
                    }

                    if let category = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "category") as! String?{
                        saveItem(itemToSave: category, key: "category")
                    }

                    if let rating = self.newRecipeView.ratingTextField.text{
                        saveItem(itemToSave: rating, key: "rating")
                    }

                    if let time = self.newRecipeView.timeTextField.text{
                        saveItem(itemToSave: time, key: "time")
                    }

                    if let directions = self.newRecipeView.directionsTextField.text{
                        saveItem(itemToSave: directions, key: "directions")
                    }

                    fetchData()
                    print(recipes)


                    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    _ = self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
            })
```

Method which save data:

```
func saveItem(itemToSave: String, key: String){
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Recipe", in: managedContext)
let item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: managedContext)
item.setValue(itemToSave, forKey: key)
do{
    try managedContext.save()
    recipes.append(item)
}catch{
    print("\(error)")
}
```

}

Method which fetch data:

```
func fetchData(){
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Recipe")
do{
    let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    recipes = results as! [NSManagedObject]
}catch{
    print("\(error)")
}
```

}

Comment: i don't see any mistakes in your code. i was thinking you may overwrite, but thats not the case

Comment: how do you instantiate `recipes`?

Comment: how do you call `recipes`?

Comment: I've updated my post.See the details from the images.

Comment: well. in the last image, you are printing only the last, that is desired?

Comment: and in your fetchData, please `print(results)`

Comment: because i have a feeling, that `results` may be an array with only one item and you overwrite it, instead of append

Comment: @DavidSeek Yes,it's because I've noticed that only the last item (in this case "directions") has the correct value.The other ones have a nil value because they aren't the last items.If I `print(results)` the output is the same.

Comment: ah now i get it. so you're storing different Recipes, but only for example "title" is saved, but "rating", "time" etc is not or what?

Comment: with your edit you just made it more unclear what your problem is

Comment: @DavidSeek Yes, I want to do what you have just written

Comment: what is your code for that bro? you have just provided to code to save a title. not to save rating or category. how do you expect anyone to be able to help you like that? :)

Comment: i have told you, that your code is fine and your problem is not even part of the code nor the QUESTION itself. you're not asking for what your problem is bro

Comment: i see your problem now. the problem is, that you store a new entity for every single text part that you have... i will write an answer

Comment: please provide the code from the screenshots as code, not as screenshots. so i can copy them

Comment: @DavidSeek I've updated the post with the code.

Comment: see my answer bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you create a new `Recipe` for every `item`.

You need to change your function to the following:

```
func saveItem(title: String, rating: String, category: String, time: String, directions: String){
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Recipe", in: managedContext)
    let item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: managedContext)

    recipe.setValue(title, forKey: "title")
    recipe.setValue(rating, forKey: "rating")
    recipe.setValue(category, forKey: "category")
    recipe.setValue(time, forKey: "time")
    recipe.setValue(directions, forKey: "directions")

    do{
        try managedContext.save()
        recipes.append(recipe)
    }catch{
        print("\(error)")
    }
}
```

And then call it by:

```
saveItem(title: self.newRecipeView.titleTextField.text, rating: self.newRecipeView.ratingTextField.text, category: (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "category") as! String?), time: self.newRecipeView.timeTextField.text, directions: self.newRecipeView.directionsTextField.text)
```

Comment: you're welcome. glad to help. please don't forget to check as answered and upvote